# Problem in matplotlib plotting axes with twinx

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm new to matplotlib. I'm writing a Stock Market application in Python.

In the application I have a chart with 2 different line-graphs to display. One is "Price" and the other is "VVAP Indicator". I'm trying to plot it using matplotlib twinx() function, so that both of them share the same x-axis.

The problem is: the price dataset has a length of 100, while the "VVAP Indicator" dataset has a length of just 1 (it will increase to 100 as new data is fetched from the server and calculated).

Here is my code:

```
 self.figure, ax1 = plt.subplots()
 ax1.plot(prices_dataframe, 'b-')
 ax2 = ax1.twinx()
 ax2.plot(vwaps_dataframe, 'r-')
 plt.autoscale(enable=True, axis='x')
 plt.title("Intraday with VWAP")
 plt.grid()
 helper.chart_figure = self.figure
```

Here are the datasets:

[image]

And here is what I get on the charts:

[image]

How do I solve this? Do I need to pad up the second dataset with dummy rows? Or is there a more easy and elegant solution to my problem? Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to the issue in the dataset image:

[image]

The first dataset was having timezone-aware datetime objects, while in the second dataset I was inserting date and time as a string.

I also had to add the following lines to make the x axis display the proper time in my timezone:

```
ax1.xaxis_date(tz='Asia/Kolkata')
ax2.xaxis_date(tz='Asia/Kolkata')
```